# Add delay to mouseleave in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code in my site and I was wondering how I could add a delay to the mouseleave function

```
$target.mouseenter(function(e){
                var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                ddimgtooltip.showbox($, $tooltip, e)
            })
            $target.mouseleave(function(e){
             var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid);
             setTimeout(function() { ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip); }, 4000);
            })

            $target.mousemove(function(e){
                var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid)
                ddimgtooltip.positiontooltip($, $tooltip, e)
            })
            if ($tooltip){ //add mouseenter to this tooltip (only if event hasn't already been added)
                $tooltip.mouseenter(function(){
                    ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $(this))
                })
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem with just a timer would be if you mouse left and then re-entered it would still hide after that timer completed.  Something like the following might work better because we can cancel the timer whenever the mouse enters the target.

```
var myTimer=false;
$target.hover(function(){
    //mouse enter
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
},
function(){
    //mouse leave
    var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid);
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip);
    },500)
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean, just tested the first function and it did exactly what you said, can you help edit my edited posts to make the change that you suggested?

Comment: +1 for the cancel logic. I think it should probably be `$target.one("hover", function()...` to get rid of the event after it fires.

Answer (score 5):

```
(function($){
   $.fn.lazybind = function(event, fn, timeout, abort){
        var timer = null;
        $(this).bind(event, function(){
            timer = setTimeout(fn, timeout);
        });
        if(abort == undefined){
            return;
        }
        $(this).bind(abort, function(){
            if(timer != null){
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);


$('#tooltip').lazybind(
    'mouseout',
    function(){
        $('#tooltip').hide();
    },
    540,
    'mouseover');
```

http://www.ideawu.com/blog/2011/05/jquery-delay-bind-event-handler-lazy-bind.html

Comment: Works perfectly. Seems like the best solution to me :) Nicely packaged for jQuery, too. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and an anonymous function for this:

```
$target.mouseleave(function(e){
 var $tooltip=$("#"+this._tipid);
 setTimeout(function() { ddimgtooltip.hidebox($, $tooltip); }, 250);
})
```

This would delay it 250ms after leaving before it hides, you can just adjust that value as needed.

Comment: thank you that's awesome, now when I mouseover another one is there a way I can skip that timeout?

Comment: @Dustin - Yep, but I can't say how exactly without seeing your `mouseenter` function for the other elements, need a bit more context added to the question.

Comment: @Dustin - What is `$target`? Since you'll have to target the rest of those elements to hide their tooltips.

Comment: the whole script is too long to post is there an email or messenger I can send you the code at?

Comment: @Dustin - Check out jsfiddle or jsbin, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bLQrn/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function I just wrote:

```
$.fn.hoverDelay = function(handlerIn, handlerOut, delay) {
    if(delay === undefined) delay = 400;
    var timer;
    this.hover(function(eventObject) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        handlerIn.apply(this,eventObject);
    }, function(eventObject) {
        timer = setTimeout(handlerOut.bind(this, eventObject), delay);
    });
};
```

It works just like the normal `$.hover` except there is a 400ms delay before the mouse leave event is called (which is cancelled if you move your mouse back in within that timeframe).