# How to delay mouseleave action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a menu. In this menu I have some hidden submenus, so I'm showing it after hover action. I have also some delay effect on submenus showing. Now I want to add the same effect on hiding it. But it's not working. Also how can I add some delay on hover/mouseenter next menu element?

```
$('.main_menu ul li').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var self = this,
            time = 200;
        $(self).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened');
        }, time));
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        var self = this,
            time = 200;
        clearTimeout($(self).data('timer'));
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
        }, time);
    }
});
```

Comment: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709255/add-delay-to-mouseleave-in-jquery*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made good solve for this question, so:

```
var timer;
$('.main_menu ul li').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var self = this;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened');
        }, 100)
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (!$(self).children('.sub_menu_main').is(":hover")){
                 $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
            }
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you don't use `self` in your mouseleave event? What is `this` in that function? Put a `debugger` statement to see if `this` is the thing you think it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `.delay()`?

http://api.jquery.com/delay/